# Unable to bind / connect to remote service created as part of an AAR library

Tags: android, service, aar

I have created a service which lives within a library. The library is then included in another project which attempts to launch the service. I am using AIDL to interact however when I attempt to connect to the service my onConnected method is never hit.

From the log files I can see the following error:

```
D/ActivityManager: bindService callerProcessName:com.something.services.dummyproject, calleePkgName: com.something.services.dummyproject, action: com.something.services.dummyservice.IDummyService

W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.something.services.dummyservice.IDummyService cmp=com.something.services.dummyproject/com.something.services.dummyservice.IDummyService } U=0: not found

D/ActivityManager: bindService callerProcessName:com.something.services.dummyproject, calleePkgName: com.something.services.dummyservice.service, action: null

W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.something.services.dummyservice.service/.DummyService } U=0: not found
```

The DummyService.java file is as follows:

```
package com.something.services.dummyservice.services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;

import com.something.services.dummyservice.IDummyService;

public class DummyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    private final IDummyService.Stub mBinder = new IDummyService.Stub() {
        @Override
        public String dummyHello() throws RemoteException {
            return "Hello";
        }

        @Override
        public void exit() throws RemoteException {
            stopSelf();
        }
    };
}
```

The DummyService Manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.something.services.dummyservice">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service
            android:name=".services.DummyService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            tools:ignore="ExportedService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The IDummyService.aidl file is as follows:

```
// IDummyService.aidl
package com.something.services.dummyservice;

// Declare any non-default types here with import statements

interface IDummyService {

    String dummyHello();

    void exit();
}
```

I'm generating a .aar file with the above.

I've then included that library into my main project file.

The manifest in my main project is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.something.services.dummyproject">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The MainActivity.java file is as follows:

```
package com.something.services.dummyproject;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.something.services.dummyservice.IDummyService;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private IDummyService mDummyService;

    @Bind(R.id.btnStartService)
    Button btnStartService;

    @Bind(R.id.btnEndService)
    Button btnEndService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

                 btnStartService.setOnClickListener(startServiceOnClickListener);
        btnEndService.setOnClickListener(endServiceOnClickListener);
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            mDummyService = IDummyService.Stub.asInterface(service);

            dummyHello();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mDummyService = null;
        }
    };

    private final View.OnClickListener startServiceOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View completeButton) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.something.services.dummyservice.IDummyService.class);
            intent.setAction(IDummyService.class.getName());
            bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    };

    private final View.OnClickListener endServiceOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View completeButton) {
                exitService();
        }
    };

    private void dummyHello() {
        try {
            String response = mDummyService.dummyHello();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void exitService() {
        try {
            if (mDummyService != null) {
                mDummyService.exit();
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The dummyProject also contains the exact same AIDL file. In both cases the AIDL file lives in an aidl folder which lives alongside the src\JAVA folder. That contains a package folder which contains the AIDL file.

Any help with identifying why I'm unable to connect to the service is very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. When I try to do this:

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.something.services.dummyservice.DummyService);
            intent.setAction(IDummyService.class.getName());
            bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

I get the error within A/S 'Cannot resolve DummyService'. So, I'm thinking that this means that my service that exists within the library isn't visible within my project ?

Comment: I have, but that also fails even if I explicitly state the entire path, which is making me think that along with what you wrote (i.e. it should be DummyService.class that I call), the service within my library is not visible to my application at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Just tried that whilst my app that includes the library is running. I get the following error:
"Error: Not found; no service started."

Comment: None. The call is:
com.something.services.dummyservice.DummyService

(Note, I moved DummyService outside of the subfolder services to make it simpler and then re-built and re-added my library to my application)

Comment: Sorry. None.

./adb shell am startservice com.something.services.dummyservice.DummyService

Comment: The service doesn't need to be declared in in the manifest for my application does it ? I think that as I've included the library it should automatically merge the manifests and thus should be visible.

Comment: Okay. I tried that as follows:
adb shell am startservice -n com.something.services.dummyservice/.DummyService but get the the same error. That matches the package name in the service's manifest along with the android.name element.

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you. The application is com.something.services.dummyproject and the service library is com.something.services.dummyservice

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have answer to my issue.
I've had the something similar on Android 12 and found that package and intent should be whitelisted inside the calling app(library) in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.example.packagewithservice" />
    <intent>
        <action com.example.BIND_SERVICE" /> 
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring